# Transmit a message and 4xx status code from contract

Tags: return, http

`eosio_assert()` transmits a message and a status code 500. Is there a contract method that transmits a message and a status code of my choice, such as a 4xx status code?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not.  In the instance of an eosio_assert error message the node is telling you there was an error.  It's not like a standard web application where you can decide the status code to return.  You should expect a 200 or 500 when hitting the RPC endpoint with a valid signed transaction.

Comment: Why? Can you point me to a discussion of this design decision?